# making a calculation using JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Why this isn't working?
I also did this by assigning the result back to the input field but that didn't work and still this is not showing an alert which should show the result..

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function calculate() {
       var calculateit=document.getElementById('disp');
       var pluscharacter=/+/;
       var matchplus=calculateit.search(pluscharacter);
       var inputlength=calculateit.length;
           if(matchplus!=-1 && matchplus!=0 matchplus!=inputlength) {
              answer=calculateit[0]+calculateit[1];
              alert("Your answer is: "+answer+" Is it?");
    }
    }
    </script>
```

Comment: What is the alert display? Or what is the error?

Comment: For better understanding, Please provide a **working demo** (*code snippet,jsfiddle ...*)

Comment: Syntax error at `matchplus!=0 matchplus!=inputlength`, learn how to use the console

Comment: actually i m new to javascripting and all that, i m assigned to make a simple calculator which should calculate some basic arithmetic and logical operation..here what i m doing is (getting the input entered by user and then after searching from it that is there any '+' character if there then split that input on the basis of this character and then two parts of input 1st one before plus character and 2nd one after the plus character, and then simply calculating the summation and displaying it back..but it isn't going in a good way..

Comment: #Adeneo!
here i m using 
(matchplus!=0 matchplus!=inputlength)
to avoid inputs like this... (+32) or (43+)

Comment: here it is the complete code..

Answer (score 2):

Your if statement isn't a valid condition. Try:

```
if(matchplus!=-1 && matchplus!=0 && matchplus!=inputlength)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var calculateit = document.getElementById('disp');
var matchplus = calculateit.search(pluscharacter);
```

`calculateit` is  a `Node` doesn't have any `search()` method.

Answer (score 0):

You're doing stuff you don't need to do - just split the string.  You also need to get the innerHTML - THAT's the string.  Or you can get the "value" from an input field instead.  I'd trim it to get rid of the white space around the equation, though the parseInt would take care of that as well.  I'd also push the answer into another div.  Here's a jsfiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/mckinleymedia/9ezky35v/2/

With this HTML:

```
<h3>Equation</h3>
<div id="disp">12+12</div>
<h3>Answer</h3>
<div id="answer"></div>
```

You can use this script:

```
function calculate() {
  var calculateit = document.getElementById('disp').innerHTML.trim(),
      numbers = calculateit.split('+'),
      answerDiv = document.getElementById('answer');
  if ( numbers.length > 1 ) {
    answer = parseInt(numbers[0]) + parseInt(numbers[1]);
    answerDiv.innerHTML = "Your answer is: <b>" + answer + "</b>, Right?";
  } else {
    answerDiv.innerHTML = "I can't calculate that equation.";
  }
}
calculate();
```